# Fill empty vectors in a loop

Tags: r

I created four empty vectors (`series_p_river`) which I would like to fill in a loop instead of one by one. The data that is supposed to be filled in the vectors contain mean values of four different river basins (Main, Danube, Isar and Inn), one value for each river and each timestep. For example `Main.4_mean, Danube.18_mean, Isar.2_mean, Inn.8_mean`. The number of time steps `ntime` is the length of the empty vectors.

The one by one way works well of course, but is not very elegant:

```
for (j in 1:ntime) {
  series_p_Main[j] <- get(paste0("Main.", j, "_mean"))
  series_p_Danube[j] <- get(paste0("Danube.", j, "_mean"))
  series_p_Isar[j] <- get(paste0("Isar.", j, "_mean"))
  series_p_Inn[j] <- get(paste0("Inn.", j, "_mean"))
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a loop or in another way?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you'll be doing something similar with each river, so I generally recommend a list of vectors instead of individual objects in your environment. That suggests that instead of `series_p_Main`, you might then need to reference `series_p[["Main"]]`. The added benefit of using a list, though, is that when you do the same to each vector, you can use `lapply` instead of manually doing each one.

For instance,

```r
ntime <- 3
series_p <- lapply(setNames(nm = c("Main", "Danube", "Isar", "Inn")),
                   function(nm) sprintf("%s.%s_mean", nm, seq_len(ntime)))
str(series_p)
# List of 4
#  $ Main  : chr [1:3] "Main.1_mean" "Main.2_mean" "Main.3_mean"
#  $ Danube: chr [1:3] "Danube.1_mean" "Danube.2_mean" "Danube.3_mean"
#  $ Isar  : chr [1:3] "Isar.1_mean" "Isar.2_mean" "Isar.3_mean"
#  $ Inn   : chr [1:3] "Inn.1_mean" "Inn.2_mean" "Inn.3_mean"
series_p[["Main"]]
# [1] "Main.1_mean" "Main.2_mean" "Main.3_mean"
```

Or if `ntime` is actually a vector, then remove `seq_len`:

```r
ntime <- c(4, 8, 12)
series_p <- lapply(setNames(nm = c("Main", "Danube", "Isar", "Inn")), function(nm) sprintf("%s.%s_mean", nm, ntime))
series_p[["Main"]]
# [1] "Main.4_mean"  "Main.8_mean"  "Main.12_mean"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for the tip with the lists. When I apply that solution it creates a list with four elements, each of those containing a series of each river. So far so good. But the single series do not contain the ```ntime``` mean values, but character values, for example ```"Main4_mean"``` instead of ```1.26```. Do you know what to do?

Comment: I have no idea. Please fill out your question with sample data (output from `dput(head(x))` for whatever objects are relevant) and expected output given that sample data.